# React Antd - Found 2 elements with non-unique warning

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, antd

I am using the `Carousel` component each holding a different component. One holds a `form` and the other an external library `react-input-otp` component.

[image: Edit pensive-einstein-uucvm]

If you look at webview https://uucvm.csb.app/ console

[image]

Even if I add `name` on each item which I believe equals to `id` of the component it still throws the warning. Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can prevent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this [issue](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/940) on slick which used by antd `Carousel`

> It's because you have an infinite carousel with 3 slides to show and
> in center mode. What this means is that Slick needs to place "clones"
> of those slides at each end of the carousel so that when you approach
> the end it has a copy to display at the beginning as it "infinitely"
> goes around.

And because of that clones, your Form components also duplicates and leads to id duplication that's why you get the warning.

You can fix this warning by setting `infinite` prop of `Carousel` to false:

```
<Carousel 
    afterChange={onChange}
    infinite={false}
>
    ...
</Carousel>
```

here is the [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-rain-uprs6?file=/index.js)

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the info!